# Как быть если остаток от деления не помещается в беззнаковый тип?

Tags: алгоритм

У меня есть два беззнаковых числа и требуется найти остаток от деления суммы этих чисел на третье, также беззнаковое число. Как это сделать аккуратно, если учитывать, что сумма двух беззнаковых вообще говоря не обязана влезать в тип по размеру (т.е. возможно переполнение)

Comment: Если есть возможность,  то записать сумму в беззнаковое число с большей разрядностью.

Comment: _сумма чисел  при делении на некоторое число дает тот же остаток, что и сумма их остатков._

Comment: @Grundy, ну и чего? никто не дает гарантии, что после взятия остатков от каждого числа и после дальнейшего суммирования не возникнет переполнения

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Алгоритм может быть такой. Берете остатки от деления каждого делимого на делитель. Затем берете разницу между делителем и одним из остатков. Вычитаете эту разницу из второго остатка, если она превосходит второй остаток, или складываете остатки, если они меньше в сумме делителя и получаете окончательный остаток.

Пусть имеются два беззнаковых числа `x` и `y` и делитель `d`. Тогда остаток `r` от деления `x + y` на `d` можно вычислить так.

```
r1 = x % d;
r2 = y % d;

r = r1 < ( d - r2 ) ? r1 + r2 : r1 - ( d - r2 );
```

Вот пример функции для типа `unsigned int` на C/C++

```
unsigned int remainder(unsigned int x, unsigned int y, unsigned int d)
{
    unsigned int r1 = x % d;
    unsigned int r2 = y % d;

    return r1 < (d - r2) ? r1 + r2 : r1 - (d - r2);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Просто складываете остатки от деления и еще раз применяете к ним операцию получения остатка. На C/C++

```
unsigned r = (x %d + y %d) %d;
```

На Pascal

```
r = (x mod d + y mod d) mod d;
```

Судите сами:
пусть `x = kd+r1`, `y=md+r2`. Тогда `(x+y)%d = ((k+m)d + (r1+r2))%d = (r1+r2)%d`. Очевидно, что это соответствует `(x%d + y%d) %d = (r1+r2)%d`...

Если ну очень хочется применить ветвление (что как раз плохо для современных процессоров), то можно проверить, больше ли сумма остатков третьего числа, и если больше, то вычесть его...

P.S. Есть, правда, один нехороший случай - если `d` больше половины представимого диапазона, и сумма остатков переваливает за диапазон. Этот случай надо рассматривать отдельно, с вычитанием половины `d` из каждого из остатков. Но это уже экзотика :)

Вот примерный код:

```
unsigned mod(unsigned x, unsigned y, unsigned d)
{
    x = x % d;
    y = y % d;
    if (x+y < x) // Overflow
    {
        x -= d/2;
        y -= (d-d/2);
    }
    return (x+y)%d;
}
```

Работать будет корректно даже при, скажем, `x < d/2`. Но если кого смущает - вот еще один вариант:

```
unsigned mod(unsigned x, unsigned y, unsigned d)
{
    x = x % d;
    y = y % d;
    if (x+y < x) // Overflow
    {
        if (x < y)
        {
            y -= (d-x);
            x = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            x -= (d-y);
            y = 0;
        }
    }
    return (x+y)%d;
}
```

P.P.S. Спасибо [@PavelMayorov](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/178779/pavel-mayorov) за подсказку:

```
unsigned mod(unsigned x, unsigned y, unsigned d)
{
    x = x % d;
    y = y % d + x;
    if (y < x) y-=d;
    return y%d;
}
```

Comment: Не совсем так. Если считать, например, в uint8_t по модулю 127, то получаем: 255 % 127 = 1, 1 % 127 = 1, но (255 + 1) % 127 = 0 % 127 = 0.

Comment: @VladD Простите, но у вас как раз получилось переполнение, которого старается избежать автор вопроса. Математически 256 mod 127 = 2 (256 = 127*2+2). Если мы воспользуемся бОльшими типами, то получим эту двойку.

Comment: Ну это был как бы контрпример против рассуждения с остатками (`x = kd + r1` и т. д.).

Comment: @VladD Мое рассуждение приводилось в математическом смысле, там, где никаких переполнений...

Comment: Это да, вы же применяете его для пояснения правильности вычислений, в которых переполнение уже возможно?

Comment: @VladD Я показываю, что математически эти две формы одинаковы, т.е. `mod d mod d === mod d`. Так что если r1+r2 не вызывают переполнения, то и мой вариант не дает переполнения. Дает же он его в редком неприятном случае, который упомянут в PS.

Comment: Забавно, почему минус - что я не так написал? Где ошибка?

Comment: Минус не мой. (Хотя хотелось бы полный код, с проверкой экзотического случая, конечно.)

Comment: @VladD Добавил.

Comment: Обработка случая переполнения слишком сложная. Там надо всего-то сделать так: `x+y-d`. Ну да, будет второе переполнение - но это не страшно.

Comment: @PavelMayorov Да, подумал - согласен. подправил.

Comment: Но переполнения разрешены только для unsigned.

Comment: @Qwertiy А мы с ними и работаем. Как минимум в вопросе *"У меня есть два беззнаковых числа и требуется найти остаток от деления суммы этих чисел на третье, также беззнаковое число"*

Comment: Ага. Просто решил написать коммент для полноты картины. А то я тут недавно вечный цикл не мог сделать с интом и даблом... Долго думал, чего ж там не так, потом вспомнил, что это UB, а компилятор умный и вышвыривает цикл в половине случаев. Причём была разница, сделаю я const double или захардкожу число в условии for'а o_O